# Complex Constants

Tags: terminology, definition, meta-math

During my studies in mathematics a lot of people who are concerned about the communication of mathematics say that the term "imaginary numbers" is a misleading term. Maybe because these numbers are not any more "imagined" than other numbers. So then I thought about the other names we give to sets of numbers, like natural numbers, rational, real and irrational etc. Maybe natural numbers come to the fact that a naive view of the world, things can be described with discrete numbers. Rationals follow self-explanatory. With the reals, it gets a bit tricky because $\pi$  or $e$ aren't anything real.

But then there are physical constants that by the nature of SI units are found in reality. For example the speed of light is probably an irrational number. We would have been pretty lucky with our definitions of meters and seconds to get a fraction, so maybe that is a good reason they are called Real numbers.

Now what about complex numbers. **Are there any physical constants that are complex**?

Because if not, it would be a pretty fitting name that they are imaginary numbers. I understand the problem with the name for people who have to use complex numbers to accomplish something in the real world and have understanding/motivation issues. But compared to the field of rational polynomials, these complex numbers are clearly numbers but they can not be "found" in the real world. we just imagine them. So that would be a great name.

Comment: The speed of light in vacuum (in metres per second) is an integer: exactly $299792458$.  This is because since 1983 the metre is officially defined as the distance light travels in $1/299792458$ second.

Comment: I'm not sure it makes sense to ask if physical constants are complex or not.  For any physical constant $c$, you could consider $ci$ which then a nonreal physical constant (and in some cases such a constant may be useful.)  Conversely, if a physical constant is expressed as a complex number $c = a + bi$, you could say that $a$ and $b$ are the "real" physical constants and $c$ is just a "model".  A better question might be: are complex numbers useful in physics? And the answer there is a resounding yes - see, e.g., quantum mechanics.

Comment: You could argue Planck's constant is a complex physical constant if you define it to be the $i\hbar$ in Schrodinger's equation $i\hbar {\frac {d}{dt}}\vert \Psi (t)\rangle ={\hat {H}}\vert \Psi (t)\rangle$.

Comment: I think that my discussion of "[strict 5-ism](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/17546/8571)" is relevant.

Comment: @Robert Israel ahh interesting did not know that. i found that the gravitational constant as an other example is mesured empiracly.

Comment: @Xander Henderson interesting read. thanks